# How to use ReplaySubject such that its observers can fire repeatedly when it subscribes to a new observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to figure how to use ReplaySubject such that its observers can fire repeatedly when it subscribes to a new observable (e.g. HTTP GET).

This is provider that I used:

```
export class CatalogService {
    public borrow$: ReplaySubject<Borrow[]> = new ReplaySubject<Borrow[]>(null);

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public getBorrowView() {
        this.http.get<Borrow[]>(apiUrl + 'Borrow/View').subscribe(this.borrow$);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have two observers - one in the main component and the other in the uninstantiated child component.

The observer in the main component subscribe in the following manner:

```
this.catalogService.borrow$.subscribe(
    borrowList => {
        if (borrowList != null)
            this.pages[1].badge = borrowList.length;
    }
);
```

The observer in the uninstantiated child component subscribe in the following manner:

```
export class BorrowViewPage {
    items$: Observable<Borrow[]>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public catalogService: CatalogService, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.items$ = this.catalogService.borrow$;
    }
}
```

I want both of them to subscribe to a HTTP request and continue to respond whenever I make the function call in the main component or elsewhere: `this.catalogService.getBorrowView()`

However, this method only works once. It works fine on the child component. It just doesn't work after the first time for the main component. I tried unsubscribe it and subscribe it back, but it ended up firing too early yielding the wrong result.

Comment: Could you please explain us what you goal is, and provide the code you have tried to reach it ? What you have posted is a solution you think will work, which makes your question a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I didn't notice that adding additional information can be misleading. I removed what I attempted and left only of what I want to do and problem I encountered in doing so.